# Spring Security 3.2 separate data between users

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Spring Security - web application

Having two users with identical Permissions
UserA
UserB

and two Event objects

```
class Event {
objectId owner;
...
}
```

event1 owner set to userA
event2 owner set to userB
accessible for logged in users @

```
http://service/event1
http://service/event2
```

what is considered the best way to secure web application so that userA can only see

```
http://service/event1
```

but NOT

```
http://service/event2
```

(and reverse for the other user)

currently I have implemented solution on the controller level that is getting list of events for the user performs checks and redirect to appropriate place.. 
I do not like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the event's owner id matches the currently authenticated principal's id. See [*Obtaining information about the current user*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/technical-overview.html#d0e1877).

You could possibly then set up a URL pattern access rule that performs this check for event URLs (`/event*`). See [*Expression-Based Access Control*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/el-access.html).